# How to use jira-python to update an issuelink

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I have a jira-issue **issue_a** which is the dependency of another jira-issue **issue_b**. Now the dependency no longer holds and I want to change **issue_a** as the dependency of **issue_c**.

I want to use JIRA python API to achieve this.

```
issue = jira.issue('issue_a')
links = issue.fields.issuelinks
for link in links:
    if link.type.name == 'Dependency' and link.inwardIssue.key == 'issue_b":
        link.inwardIssue = jira.issue('issue_c')
```

Debugging shows that the correct link has been selected, but after the last line been executed, the actual dependency do not update in jira web page. Looks like only a cloned variable is changed but the original data storage keeps the same.

I also tried the *update* method as the following

```
link.update('inwardIssue'={'key':'issue_c'})
link.inwardIssue.update('fields'={'key':'issue_c'})
link.update('fields'={'inwardIssue':'issue_c'})
```

But all of them gives error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Can anyone helps me out?

Comment: Have you tried to create a new link instead of overwriting?

Comment: Yes, deleting the original link and create a new link works. Thank you for the suggestion.